# how to get array of integers in dataweave

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave

I have input values as 
    {
      {Id:"1"},
      {Id:"2"},
      {Id:"3"}
   }

I want output as array {1,2,3} in integer formats using DataWeave in mule anypoint studio so that I can use payload for querying records from sql server database instead looping using for each processor .

I want to use it as

```
select * from tblQuotes where id in #[payload]
```

**update**:
It is required like

```
       select * from tblQuotes where id in (1,2,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
(payload map {
    id : $.Id as :number
}).*id
```

For input as

`[{"Id":"1"}, {"Id":"2"}, {"Id":"3"}]`

Output

`[1,2,3]`

Hope this helps

Comment: It gave me result as arryaList but when querying database it is not supported how can I use as select * from tblQuotes where id in #[payload] should query like select * from tblQuotes where id in (1,2,3)

Comment: how can i achieve same thing so that I don't need to query db each iteration.

Comment: You can use joinBy function of dataweave. like `.*id joinBy ","`  you will get output as `1,2,3` . Then use this payload as `select * from tblQuotes where id in (#[payload]) `

Answer (score 1):

```
output: [{"Id":"1"}, {"Id":"2"}, {"Id":"3"}] map ((value , index) -> value.Id as :number)

OR

output: payload map ((value , index) -> value.Id as :number)
For input: 
[{"Id":"1"}, {"Id":"2"}, {"Id":"3"}]
Output: 
[1,2,3]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain how to solve the problem and provide the code as an example or reference. Code-only answers can be confusing and lack context.